# undoing pending changes through visual studio hangs for large number of changes

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am using vs2012 with tfs. The whole things hangs when i try to undo a big changeset for an entire solution. The workaround I have adopted is to do this project by project. Is there a better way to do this?

I would re-map tfs to a fresh directory but then all those checkouts would still need to be undone. Any suggestions from people who have encountered and resolved this problem are welcome.

Comment: The annoying part is that TFS doesnt even tell you what's going on in the background when it is trying to get through a big big changeset with a lot of projects

Comment: It's still the same with VS2015

Comment: feeling your pain... I misclicked on the top folder of a massive branch and did check out. Took 2 sec. Undoing this checkout on the 6000 items is so slow I have to do it in chunks of few hundreds items. There goes half an hour of work :(

Comment: Good thing most of us are on git or some other source control system now

Answer (score 56, accepted):

[`tf undo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c72skhw4) from the Developer Command Prompt for VS2012 slightly faster than the IDE.

e.g: `tf undo $/YourTeamProject /recursive`

Comment: Thank you, this also worked for Visual Studio 2013. "[S]lightly faster" is a big understatement if there are thousands of files! :)

Comment: Hurrah for this answer. I had a huge directory (800MB+ of about 27.000 files) to undo. VS became unresponsive. It seems "slightly faster" here means the difference between "unworkable" and "blazing fast". :)

Comment: I used in VS2013 and tfs 2013, but I need to change the syntax to: tf undo /workspace:[your Work space] [The physical address of your tfs directory to undo] /recursive

Comment: VS2015 I used 
>tf undo C:\directorytoundo /recursive

Comment: great answer to archive I was in a big trouble

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't do much - it sends an `Undo` request to the server and in response receives the data to put on disk.  If you have a slow connection to the server or you have a slow proxy (virus scanner, maybe?) then this can slow things down significantly.

If you find this happening a lot, your best course of action is to upgrade to TFS 2012 on the server, Visual Studio 2012 on the client, and then ensure that you are using a Local Workspace.  In this case, you need not contact the server to undo.

Comment: Seriously, the only way to solve the problems of TFS is not to use TFS.

Comment: @max Certainly, a process-heavy checkout/edit/checkin workflow is not for everybody.  TFS offers local workspaces (edit/merge/commit) models if you prefer that workflow.  And, of course, DVCS using Git.

Comment: yes, sorry. I was having a bad day where a tfs operation caused visual studio to hang for the.better part of an hour.. an operation which wouldn't even be needed if we were using git or subversion..

Answer (score 3):

I have found that sometimes VS is trying to display an *'Are You Sure'*  pop up message and this is hidden off screen somewhere.
Sometimes pressing `Escape` or `Enter` will get past the hidden message and release the freeze.

Comment: This seems like a very real possibility. I'm using remote desktop, and I'm not seeing the confirmation prompt when it locks up. Likely due to a difference in monitor configuration between local and remote.

Answer (score 1):

A more detailed and step-by-step solution to the issue which works also on VS2019 and VS2022 is the following:

1- Open the developer command prompt. You can do that from Visual Studio, type developer command prompt in the search field at the top.

2- get the status of all checkouted files using the following command:

```
tf status "$/" /s:tfs /recursive /format:detailed
```

3- Then you'll get a list of similar items to the following:
[image]

Then copy the path of the directory you want to batch undo everything under from 1 in the img. Fill in that in the command below between the double quotations instead of PUT_1_HERE. Do the same for 2 and 3 without double quotations.

```
tf undo "PUT_1_HERE" /workspace:PUT_2_HERE;PUT_3_HERE /recursive
```

4- Execute the command and Voila it should take some seconds regardless how large the number of files to undo is.

Note: Previous answers about closing the solution, or unloading the project don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I did notice that when we use multiple screen(multiple monitors) VS gets hang while performing the 'undo pending changes'. Use only one to get around this bug.

Answer (score 0):

Perform the undo **after** you close the solution in Visual Studio, then it will go much faster.

Visual studio listens to source control changes when the solution is open, which makes it take too much time if many files.

1- [image: close solution]

2- Go to Teams Explorer and perform the undo

Otherwise, the tf command works perfectly but is a bit risky if your files-to-undo are scattered.

Credits to Kashif Khan https://stackoverflow.com/users/931622/kashif-khan